# Prevent losing a digital Signature when a document is saved?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, certificate, digital-signature

### The question

What is an effective work-around to prevent a Digital Signature dropping from a file when it's saved? Or, What would be an efficient way to replicate saving data to a Macro Enabled MS Word Document with a Digital Signature?

### Some context...

Long story short, my workplace now require Macro enabled files to be signed with a Digital Signature otherwise Macros are disabled (with no enable option) due to a security policy update. My concern is specifically with MS Office Applications using VBA.

**Note:** I have no say in the matter nor do I have the ability to discuss this with the team that implemented the change.

**Also Note:** I unfortunately don't know what type of Signature will be applied to my document or where it will be from.

With that said, **I am not very familiar with Digital Signatures** however to my understanding once a file has been signed with one, if you <s>save the file</s> [update any code in the project it will lose the Digital Signature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Digitally-sign-your-macro-project-956e9cc8-bbf6-4365-8bfa-98505ecd1c01).

I had just about finished developing a MS Word Document containing a fair bit of VBA and `UserForms` when the policy was changed and here lies my potential problem.

### For clarity

The MS Word document is an Assessment used throughout various training for the business to ensure staff have a sound understanding of newly learned work types.

There are 3 stages that the document is saved at:

1. Assessment Creation
2. Participant Completion
3. Assessor Marking

**Step 1** involves a `UserForm` that when completed writes the user input values to various bookmarks (both placeholder and enclosing) pre-set on the blank document. The Document is then programmatically saved and re-named from "Assessment Template" to "[Skill Type] Assessment [Assessment Number]" (with the '[]' variables assigned per user inputs).

**Step 2** involves a `UserForm` that requests some basic user data (name, location, team number etc) and displays the contents of enclosed bookmarks from the document in some `UserForm` `labels` as questions, with `TexBox` sections to provide an answer. This is then submitted programmatically via email attachment which involves the document being saved and re-named to add "_[Participants Name]" to the end of the file name.

**Step 3** involves a facilitator marking the assessment with aid of yet another `UserForm` and then submitting the results to the participants team leader via email (again using VBA). Here the document is saved as macro free as it's only sent as reference of the result.

### In summary

So based on my understanding that once the <s>document is saved</s> VBE project has any updates the Digital Signature will no-longer be valid and my project is no-longer useful in our current work environment.

I'm trying to better my understanding of how the digital Signatures work (if different to my current understanding) and I'm trying to work out some alternate solutions <s>to the document being saved and subsequently losing the Signature</s> if required.

As an example of what I'm attempting, a colleague has replaced saving an excel form with writing the user inputs to a `.bin` file saved to the users documents (only 5 short inputs). As this form is never saved (in fact saving the document is disabled) this was a suitable method for replacing the `SaveAs` prompt and keeping the WorkBook as Macro Enabled.

**Note:** I don't believe this is a suitable solution to follow for my document due the the amount of data that would be input to my document (not to mention the above would only show results for the user that made the changes and nobody else).

### Update

It seems to be the file that was tested has a function that writes to the VBE (along with the worksheet is a big part of the project) so this may be what's caused the confusion I have with changes made causing the signature to drop.

As I now understand a bit more about the Signatures (I may have simply asked here too soon) and the actual situation regarding other files in the environment, I'm thinking if the Document is Digitally Signed and no changes are made in the VBE thereafter, the document can be saved with changes made to the document contents and this will not impact the validity of the Signature?

Comment: "So based on my understanding that once the document is saved the Digital Certificate will no longer be valid, my project is no longer useful in our current work environment." - What?  The same certificate can be used to sign multiple files.  Your assumption isn't correct.  A certificate can expire, and still be valid, until its revoked.  Saving a document will not make the certificate invalid.  You need to get more information about the certificate before we can answer any of your questions.

Comment: I think you are mixing "Digital Certificate" and "Digital Signature". A certificate isn't linked to any document or file, the signature is. The certificate is used to verify the signature. The signature is produced by combining the signed document and a secret key that only the person who created the certificate possesses. If you change the document, the signature is invalid and cannot be re-created without the secret key.

Comment: @Ramhound 'What?' indeed! Half the battle here is the complexity of the work environment on top of lack of communication (this was just updated one day, no warning) and as Nathan pointed out, I am very confused. To sum it up, we have been told all files require a 'Digital Certificate' to allow VBA to be used. Per some Excel testing, if the file is subsequently saved, the 'authentication' is lost and VBA or Macros are no-longer enabled. I'm finding it hard to try and clarify my question as I really am not sure what I'm asking exactly. I guess I just don't want to abandon such long hard work!

Comment: @Nathan.EilishaShiraini that has actually helped clarify in my mind kinda what's going on but per my above comment, I can only go by what I've been told, which is really not much at all. I'm feeling like there are some missing puzzle pieces here and this may be far more complicated than expected...

Comment: A digital certificate, specifically a certificate used to sign documents, cannot become invalid.  The digital signature can become invalid.  So which one are you asking about specifically?  I stand by the fact we cannot help you unless you provide information about the certificate.

Comment: Being in the business of writing VBA solutions for over 20 years, I have never heard or have been told by clients that my Digital Code 3 Signing Certificate was or would be removed after saving the file. If the macro enabled file is saved into format that does not support macros, then yes maybe the certificate might go away, but so does the VBA code ... so it's a moot point. Anyway, you need a Digital Code 3 Signing Certificate and they are available from many sources.

Comment: @ramhound there is a 100% chance I've been advised of the incorrect terminoligy. At work Today I'll do some digging to clarify. I fully understand the question is not clear enough to provide and answer and I'll do my best to get some clarity and return. Being new to SuperUser would it be best to leave this question and make edits as required or delete it and start fresh once i have clarity? I only ask as I can see from yours and the other responses that my question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @richmichaels thanks for the info! I'll try find out what certificates and the like are being used. Either way I don't have a voice in the matter but it's great info none the less!

Comment: @RichMichaels: I think we're mixing up two methods of signing a MS Office document: when you sign just the VBA module, vs when you sign the entire document (code and content). Samuel needs the former, but is thinking about behavior of the latter.